# Multidomain duplicate website

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I redesigned and redevelop an old website for a client with different offices of their company.

Let's say for example: www.company-sydney.com.au, www.company-brisbane.com.au, www.company-melbourne.com.au

Im gonna replicate the sydney site along with its content to have the brisbane and melbourne website up as well. There are only minor changes on some images and contact information but most of the pages of all sites are the same.

Will that affect the SEO and ranking of each of the site?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, this is duplicate content and will harm your rankings

Comment: If you use a canonical tag which is normally used for duplicate content, only one site will rank. I suggest you combine all of the sites and getting it to rank using the various geo location ranking methods.

Answer (score 1):

The most essential aspect for lasting success on Google ranking is content authority. If you are making a site about a given city it has to specific to that city. Do everything but duplication.